# Wordpress WP_Filesystem() doesn't rewrite file

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to generate dynamicly css file.

```
global $my_options;
WP_Filesystem();
global $wp_filesystem;

$css = '';
$file = './css/compile.css';

$css .= '
a{
    color: '. $my_options['link-color']['regular'] .';
} 
a:hover{
    color: '. $my_options['link-color']['hover'] .';
} 
'; 
if(!$wp_filesystem->put_contents($file, $css, FS_CHMOD_FILE)) {
    echo 'Generating CSS error!';
}
var_dump($wp_filesystem->get_contents($file));
```

var_dump returns `string(69) " a{ color: #81d742; } a:hover{ color: #1e73be; } "`, but when I observing file compile.css - it hasn't any changes. I can't figure out what is the reason for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try with replacing two lines:

```
global $my_options;    
global $wp_filesystem;
WP_Filesystem();

$css = '';
$file = './css/compile.css';

$css .= '
a{
    color: '. $my_options['link-color']['regular'] .';
} 
a:hover{
    color: '. $my_options['link-color']['hover'] .';
} 
'; 
if(!$wp_filesystem->put_contents($file, $css, FS_CHMOD_FILE)) {
    echo 'Generating CSS error!';
}
var_dump($wp_filesystem->get_contents($file));
```

i have the same problem, solved by doing this

thanks

Comment: Thanks, but content of file doesn't chages :(

Comment: i have changed the first three line orders

Comment: Yep, I saw that, but unfortunatelly this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

replace 
`$file = './css/compile.css';`

with
`$file = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'css/compile.css';`

it will work fine..